# Maven: Managing Spring configurations

Tags: spring, maven, configuration

I have several set's of Spring configurations (XML files for bean initialization and properties files), for different kind of services/servers. I've also use maven to manage the dependencies and build (alternating with eclipse).

My intent was to have a flag I could pass to maven to build the project with a selected configuration profile.

Example:

```
mvn package production
```

will put the conf/production files in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Use maven profiles. Switch them with `-P` on the command line or use the various activation methods.

Comment: At [Maven Profile Best Practices](http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices) is said: "Use profiles to adapt to build-time context, not run-time context, and not (with rare exceptions) to produce alternative versions of your artifact". In my case I want to change run-time context.

Comment: Do you know about Spring Profiles? With the same build you can have different configurations and then maven loads the appropiate for your enviroment. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using the approach of Spring profiles as suggested by @gerardribas.
I've looked at the [Jhipster implementation](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) and follow that way. If somebody is following the same path, be aware that your need to upgrade your servlet version to 3.x.